# WP_Query hit max joins... How else can I build a search function that uses custom fields?

Tags: wp-query, mysql, join-tables

I'm trying to search a custom post type of "Properties", while doing so I'm also searching the custom fields using multiple (anywhere from 5-30) meta_queries. The problem is Wordpress or MySQL is throwing an error saying I hit the limit of the amount of JOIN statements that can be used.

The error: 
 [The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay]

Since I'm using WP_Query is it even possible to set those options? Any other ways I can get around this?

Here are an example of my query $args:

Here is my $args that I'm passing to WP_Query:

```
 Array
(
[numberposts] => -1
[post_type] => properties
[status] => publish
[tax_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array
            (
                [taxonomy] => markets
                [field] => id
                [terms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 27
                        [1] => 157
                    )

            )

    )

[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => sleeps
                [value] => 3
                [type] => NUMERIC
                [compare] => >=
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => minimum_rate_0_rate
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 999
                        [1] => 2750
                    )

                [type] => NUMERIC
                [compare] => BETWEEN
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [key] => management
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Professionally Managed
                        [1] => Privately Owned
                    )

                [type] => CHAR
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [key] => property_type
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Home
                        [1] => Condo
                    )

                [type] => CHAR
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [key] => number_of_bedrooms
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 15
                    )

                [type] => NUMERIC
                [compare] => BETWEEN
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [key] => total_number_of_baths
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [type] => NUMERIC
                [compare] => BETWEEN
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [key] => pet_policy
                [value] => cat dog
                [type] => CHAR
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [key] => pools_hot_tubs_and_saunas
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Hot Tub
                    )

                [type] => CHAR
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [key] => appliances_and_furniture
                [value] => Washer
                [type] => CHAR
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [key] => phone_and_internet
                [value] => Internet
                [type] => CHAR
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Maybe you could separate the big query in several smaller ones...

Comment: I'm guessing I'd have to move away from using WP_Query then? How would you suggest I go about it then?

Comment: Mhhh, difficult to say without more info...Could you put a concrete example?

Comment: Added a query example to the top. That is a pretty mild one, but that's right about when it starts to break.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966815/mysql-max-join-size-errors

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to do the trick, running it before my WP_Query:

```
$wpdb->query('SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1');
```